# How to capture elements of an object I created in a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, assign

I was trying to capture the mean of a variable (Z) for each subsample in a set of subsamples I created with a loop (in this case, I creater 100 subsamples, each having 5 observations).
However, I haven't managed to capture the mean of the variable I want (Z) for each sample and assign it to an object (in this case, a place in the vector mean_z_5). This is the code that I was trying to use:

```
mean_z_5<-vector(mode="numeric", length=100)

for (i in 1:100){
   assign(paste("muestra5",i,sep="_"), data1[sample(nrow(basetaller1),    size=5, 
           replace=TRUE), ])
   object= get(paste("muestra5",i,sep="_"))
   medias_z_5[i]<-object
}
```

Anyone with an idea what to do?

Sergio

Comment: Put them into a list, `myList <- list()` before the loop. Then `for(...)... myList[paste("muestra5",i,sep="_")] <- data1[sample(nrow(basetaller1), size=5, replace=TRUE), ]` Now, you can refer to that data.frame with `myList[["mustra5x"]]` where "x" is some integer.

Comment: `paste("muestra5",i,sep="_")` is a very cumbersome way to create an indexed collection of related data. Why not a single list or vector called `muestra5` and e.g. use `muestra5[10]` rather than `musestra5_10`? String pasting is not an efficient way of indexing.